# Possible to use XmlDataProvider with d:DataContext?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm wondering how I can use an XmlDataProvider to provide arbitrary XML data for design time use in Blend 4. I've tried a few ways of specifying it but Blend doesn't pick it up. My UI elements end up blank.

I realize Blend has functionality to generate and manage sample data but that's a lot of overhead for some of the simple user controls I have. I'm looking for something that works inline in the Xaml file (i.e. implicit schema) without a lot of extra files getting generated. Putting an XmlDataProvider in the resources and then doing a d:DataContext to reference it seemed like a good way to go but I can't make it work.

I can't use any of my viewmodel classes for this (like with a d:DesignData or using ObjectDataProvider) because they don't expose setters for all properties. Can't set those properties with design-time data if they're read-only.

How can I build a model in pure Xaml that I can bind to at design time?

Comment: which part(s) of sample data is "a lot of overhead"?

Comment: I haven't used sample data in a long time, but last I remember it ends up creating special named folders and adding files.

Comment: yes, but as far as i understand, those files are only used at design-time and NOT in the actual build

Comment: Yes anything in the mc:ignore and d: namespaces are ignored for compilation of actual Dlls

Comment: Sorry by "overhead" I don't mean runtime performance. I'm talking about how it adds a bunch of gunk to my project. I want it to be inline right next to where it's being used.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly,

I usually do thing in this way, yet, I can't get how complex your model is, but this a way that might be working for you in design time in order to test a specific datatemplate or such.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="People" XPath="/IDs" >
            <x:XData>
                <IDs>
                    <ID name="A2231" />
                    <ID name="A3dsa" />
                    <ID name="Ad21d" />
                    <ID name="Ad231" />
                </IDs>
            </x:XData>

        </XmlDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>



  <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{StaticResource People}">
            <Label Width="200" Height="200" Content="{Binding XPath=ID/@name}"/>
  </StackPanel>
```

Is that what you meant ? If not, please elaborate more.